# Overwrite a JavaScript function in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to overwrite a js function `ActionpadWidget`.
Here is the original code:

```js
var ActionpadWidget = PosBaseWidget.extend({
    template: 'ActionpadWidget',
    init: function(parent, options) {
        var self = this;
        this._super(parent, options);

        this.pos.bind('change:selectedClient', function() {
            self.renderElement();
        console.log("Payment Click");
        // console.log("Payment Click");
        // console.log("Payment Click");
        });
    },
    renderElement: function() {
        var self = this;
        this._super();
        this.$('.pay').click(function(){
            var order = self.pos.get_order();
            var has_valid_product_lot = _.every(order.orderlines.models, function(line){
                return line.has_valid_product_lot();
            });
            if(!has_valid_product_lot){
                self.gui.show_popup('confirm',{
                    'title': _t('Empty Serial/Lot Number'),
                    'body':  _t('One or more product(s) required serial/lot number.'),
                    confirm: function(){
                        self.gui.show_screen('payment');
                    },
                });
            }else{
                console.log("orginal elseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                console.log("orginal elseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                console.log("orginal elseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                self.gui.show_screen('payment');
            }
        });
        this.$('.set-customer').click(function(){
            self.gui.show_screen('clientlist');
        });
    }
});
```

Actually I want to replace the `renderElement` function completely.

So I tried like this:

```js
screens.ActionpadWidget.include({

    renderElement: function(){
        console.log('Am here',screens.ActionpadWidget.prototype);
        this._super();
        self = this;
        this.$('.pay').click(function(){
            console.log('Am here tooo!!!')
            var order = self.pos.get_order();
            var has_valid_product_lot = _.every(order.orderlines.models, function(line){
                return line.has_valid_product_lot();
            });
            if(!has_valid_product_lot){
                self.gui.show_popup('confirm',{
                    'title': _t('Empty Serial/Lot Number'),
                    'body':  _t('One or more product(s) required serial/lot number.'),
                    confirm: function(){
                        self.gui.show_screen('payment');
                    },
                });
            }else{
                // console.log("orginal elseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                // console.log("orginal elseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                console.log("Sample");
                self.gui.show_screen('payment');
            }
        });

        // this._super();
    },
});
```

The above code works successfully but only after execution of the original code.
I don't want to execute the original code.

Note:
 I commented the `this._super` in above code. That time the button for `Payment and Customer` didn't show.
How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Line below is call an inherited function.

```
this._super();
```

replace that line with a code below:

```
PosBaseWidget.prototype.renderElement.call(this);
```

Also might need to add a below line.

```
  var PosBaseWidget = require('point_of_sale.BaseWidget');
```

Complete code:

```
var PosBaseWidget = require('point_of_sale.BaseWidget');

screens.ActionpadWidget.include({

    renderElement: function(){
        console.log('Am here',screens.ActionpadWidget.prototype);
        PosBaseWidget.prototype.renderElement.call(this);
        self = this;
        this.$('.pay').click(function(){
            console.log('Am here tooo!!!')
            var order = self.pos.get_order();
            var has_valid_product_lot = _.every(order.orderlines.models, function(line){
                return line.has_valid_product_lot();
            });
            if(!has_valid_product_lot){
                self.gui.show_popup('confirm',{
                    'title': _t('Empty Serial/Lot Number'),
                    'body':  _t('One or more product(s) required serial/lot number.'),
                    confirm: function(){
                        self.gui.show_screen('payment');
                    },
                });
            }else{
                // console.log("orginal elseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                // console.log("orginal elseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                console.log("Sample");
                self.gui.show_screen('payment');
            }
        });

        // this._super();
    },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  renderElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    this._super();
    this.$('.pay').click(function(){
           var order = self.pos.get_order();
        var has_valid_product_lot = _.every(order.orderlines.models, function(line){
            return line.has_valid_product_lot();
        });
        if(!has_valid_product_lot){
           //solution
           self.gui.show_screen('products');
           //end solution
            self.gui.show_popup('confirm',{
                'title': _t('Empty Serial/Lot Number'),
                'body':  _t('One or more product(s) required serial/lot number.'),
                confirm: function(){
                    self.gui.show_screen('payment');
                },
            });
        }
        else
        {
            self.gui.show_screen('payment');
        }
    });
    this.$('.set-customer').click(function(){
        self.gui.show_screen('clientlist');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Alejandro. Please describe your answer. It is difficult to understand the problem or if the solution is suitable to those with this problem only looking at a code block.